# Laravel eloquent retrieve subfolders from folders in multi select

Tags: php, laravel

So i am working on a laravel project but I am stuck in this part:

I have a database with 2 Tables: 'folder' and 'subfolder'

i have a working crud for both of them where i also included hasMany and belongsTo. This is so i can see the folder name in the subfolder view.

Now i want to make a button in the folder view so i can view all the subfolders that have the same 'folder_id' as 'id' on folder. i already have a button that redirects with a 'id' value, but i still see all the subfolders and not the subfolders where folder_id = id.

Folder table:

```
Schema::create('folder', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments("id")->unsigned(false);
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

subfolder table:

```
   Schema::create('subfolder', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments("id")->unsigned(false);
            $table->string('name');
            $table->unsignedInteger('folder_id')->value(11)->unsigned(false)->nullable();
            $table->foreign('folder_id')->references('id')->on('folder');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

folder.index:

```
 @foreach($folders as $folder)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$folder->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$folder->name}} </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('admin.subfolder.index',$folder->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">View {{$folder->name}}</a>
            </td>

            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('admin.folder.edit',$folder->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('admin.folder.destroy', $folder->id)}}" method="post">
                  @csrf
                  @method('DELETE')
                  <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
```

subfolder controller index:

```
 $subfolders = Subfolder::with('folder')->get();
        $folders = Folder::all();

        return view('admin.subfolder.index', compact('subfolders', 'folders'));
```

If i need to add any information i will gladly do so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function in your `Subfolder` controller:

```
public function index($folder_id)
{
    $subfolders = Subfolder::where('folder_id', $folder_id)->with('folder')->get();
    $folders = Folder::all();

    return view('admin.subfolder.index', compact('subfolders', 'folders'));
}
```

Comment: if i do that i get the error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\admin\SubfolderController::index(), 1 passed in /Users/Delano/projectname /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected

and it shows me this:    public function index(Request $request, $folder_id)

Comment: @Delanovanlonden Remove the `Request` parameter then, as per my update.

Answer (score 0):

For getting only the specific subfolders from a folderId you can apply a whereHas condition on the eloquent:

```
$folders = Subfolder::whereHas('folder', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('id', $folderId);
})->get();
```

this will return only those subfolders who have matching folder ID.
I hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: do i need to add this in the subfolder controller index? or somewhere else?

Comment: this piece of code should be added to the function from where you are reteriving the subfolders if that function is the index from the SubfolderController then yes